# True or false? If $\eta$ is an explicitly defined incomputable number, then no formal system can pin down the value $\eta$ to arbitrary precision.

Tags: computability, foundations, formal-systems

Let $\eta$ denote an explicitly defined **incomputable** real number (the bounty text is faulty, and does not mention incomputability of $\eta$). Then I think that no (recursively ennumerable) formal system can pin down $\eta$ to arbitrarily many decimal places. If this is true, I'd enjoy reading a rigorous proof, since my argument is fluffy and could use more precision and generality. If its false, I'd like to see an explicit definition of an incomputable number that $\mathrm{ZFC}$ can pin down to arbitrary precision.

Here are my thoughts, restricted to the specific case of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ (or rather, formal systems implementing $\mathrm{ZFC}$). Let $\varphi$ denote an explicit definition of an incomputable real number $\eta$ in the language of set theory. So in particular, we're assuming that $\varphi$ is an $\in$-formula with one free variable $\eta$, and that $\mathrm{ZFC}$ proves the following.

1. There exists unique $\eta$ such that $\varphi.$
2. If $\varphi$, then $\eta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\eta$ is incomputable.

Now suppose for a contradiction that $\mathrm{ZFC}+\varphi$ pins down the numerical value of $\eta$ to arbitrary precision. More formally, we're assuming that for every rational number $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, the theory $\mathrm{ZFC}+\varphi$ either proves $x \leq \eta$ or else proves that $\eta \leq x$. Then we can assign to every rational number $\varepsilon > 0$ an algorithm that computes $\eta$ to $\varepsilon$-precision; this involves systematically going through all the theorems of ZFC until we find a theorem of the form "the rational number $x-\eta \leq \varepsilon$ (which is explicitly described) is within a distance $\varepsilon$ of $\eta$." I think that, by hypothesis, this only takes finitely many steps, so we're allowed to do it repeatedly, for $\varepsilon$ equal to $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8}$ etc. Then we have an algorithm that hones into the numerical value of $\eta$ to arbitrary precision, contradicting its incomputability.

**Motivation.** I was thinking that maybe we can numerically evaluate the strength of various large cardinal assumptions by studying the extent to which they narrow down the values of certain incomputable numbers. For example, it would be cool to be able to make statements like: "this large cardinal axiom makes $\mathrm{ZFC}$ at least 1000x as strong with respect to Chaitin's constant, in the sense that $\mathrm{ZFC}+\mbox{Axiom}$ can pin down every possible Chaitin's constant with at least 1000 times the precision than $\mathrm{ZFC}$."

Comment: So, you have an algorithm that determines what ZFC proves or not?

Comment: You probably need at least some computability of your system; otherwise I'm pretty sure you can build a formal system that could compute incomputable numbers.

Comment: @ZhenLin, I think I've fixed the argument somewhat.

Comment: Questions of the form "Here is a proof, is it correct" are extremely difficult to answer. One cannot say *why* a correct argument is correct, after all. To my mind, proof verification question are barely *questions* of any sort.  What would be more interesting is the motivation for the original true/false question, not a request to solve a question that the OP has already solved.

Comment: @CarlMummert, I hear what you're saying. At the same, if you think you have understood something, and if it is from a field of math you know almost nothing about, then its typically best not to just assume you have understood correctly. That's where mathematical false beliefs come from, after all. So better to ask. You're right though, it is hard to answer such questions. I included the clause "if this is true, I'd enjoy reading a rigorous proof, since my argument is fluffy and could use more precision and generality" in the bounty to try and mitigate this problem somewhat.

Comment: I did not see that in the bounty - it does change things! I hope someone will write up that answer. If you want, you could add the request to the bottom of the question - perhaps other people, like me, assume the bounty box is just boilerplate.  In any case, the argument is correct in all important respects. (In the new text, there is an issue that Chaitin's constant is not a specific number, but a family of incomputable numbers. But it is true that each element of the family is only determined to finite precision by ZFC or any other formal theory.)

Comment: @CarlMummert, thanks for the tip. I've put it in the main body of the question like you suggest.

Comment: @CarlMummert Maybe I don't know what "formal theory" means, but shouldn't it need some computability constraints to guarantee that a given incomputable number can only be determined to finite precision?

Comment: @Quinn Culver: yes, the theory needs to be effective in the sense that the theorems are effectively enumerable, and the formulas need to include ones that assert things about the real number in question. But the argument for the case of ZFC is fine, of course, because ZFC has all the relevant properties. It's not uncommon in some contexts for people to assume formal systems are effective, although the question here doesn't explicitly say it.

Comment: You should edit your body to say "explicitly defined uncomputable number," as in the title. Unless "explicitly defined" actually means something other than what I'd think it means.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, ah I finally understand your comment. Yes you're totally correct; I had forgotten the most important adjective! The problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct. Here's why:

There exists a computer program that can verify (in polynomial time, in fact) whether a string of statements in a system with finitely many axioms is a correct proof of a given theorem of that system. Therefore, the computational problem "Is $x$ a theorem?" is recursively enumerable. In particular, it is possible to write a program that, given a theorem, will eventually prove it. I would venture to guess that for most interesting theorems this is almost certainly infeasible, but there's no question that it is possible. Assuming the law of the excluded middle, this means we can determine whether or not a decidable statement in ZFC is true in a finite amount of time by simultaneously trying to prove the statement and its negation; eventually we will prove one of them.

We can also enumerate with a computer program all ordered pairs of decimal numbers of finite length that are within $\epsilon/2$ of each other if $\epsilon$ is rational. Numbers with this sort of representation are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. In our situation we have that there is a predicate $P$ that uniquely specifies a real number $y$, and we want to produce a decimal representation of $y$ that is within $\epsilon$ of $y$. Therefore we run through all pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ of decimal numbers of finite length within $\epsilon/2$ of each other and invoke our proof-finding program up to twice for each pair: once to prove $P(y)\implies x_1\leq y$ and once to prove $P(y)\implies x_2\geq y$. Eventually, if ZFC can prove these theorems, we will end up with two decimal representations of $y$ that are correct to within $\epsilon$, though likely not before the heat death of the universe.

Thus, if there is no computer program that will compute $y$ to arbitrary precision, there must be some (in fact infinitely many) statements of the form $P(y)\implies x_1\leq y$ or $P(y)\implies x_2\geq y$ that are undecidable.

Comment: @goblin Each of the steps in a proof in formal logic is very simple. All the program has to do is check whether each statement either is an axiom or follows from one of the previous statements. The reason this isn't used very often is because proofs of interesting theorems would be enormously long in this format. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_proof_checking

Comment: Hmmm okay, fair enough. Let me ponder it some more...

Comment: This starts by going fundamentally wrong. It is not the case that all true statements can be proved to be true (see Goedel, famously). The proof-checker is polynomial-time in the length of the *proof*; your method requires it to be polynomial-time in the length of the *statement to be proved*, which it is not. In quantified logic, as opposed to the propositional calculus, there are an infinite number of possible inferences from any statement, so there is no finite algorithm in general to search for proofs.

Comment: @HTFB I didn't say all true statements can be proved true, only all theorems. Things that are decidable.

Comment: @HTFB look up the definition of NP. If a solution is verifiable in polynomial time, that means you can find the solution in exponential time (because you can reduce it to an NP complete problem).

Comment: @HTFB even without a bound on the time, if a statement us decidable you can prove either it or its negation by looping over the set of all chains of implications (which is a countable set and can be enumerated).

Comment: @HTFB it's true that we don't know the length of a proof of theorem in advance. We can still eventually prove it though, so the theorems are recursively enumerable. Therefore proving a decidable statement is computable, but proving an undecidable statement may not be.

Comment: OK, I misread "theorem"! The edited version is clearer, and you are right that the time bounds are irrelevant to your argument. Nevertheless: (a) when talking about polynomial or exponential time you need to state what variable you are talking about, and your algorithm does not give any bound, even exponential, on the time taken to prove a statement: the proof may be arbitrarily much longer than the statement itself. And less irrelevantly (b): ZFC is not a finite set of axioms, as the separation and replacement axioms are schemas. (Though they can still be enumerated.)

Comment: "Proving an undecidable statement may not be computable"---does that hint that it may be?

Comment: @HTFB I don't know whether or not it is and I have no conjectures about it.

Comment: @HTFB what I mean is proving it is undecidable may be computable.

Comment: @HTFB though I'd guess there's a hierarchy of undecidability, I.e. it might be undecidable whether something is undecidable, etc.